# simple_form error messages do not go away

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, validation, simple-form

I'm using simple_form with twitter bootstrap on Rails.

Everything works great, except when showing live validations in a form-inline class.  My code for the form is:

```
<%= simple_form_for @message, 
                    url: mailing_list_path,
                    html: { class: "form-inline" },
                    method: :post,
                    validate: true do |f| %>

    <%= f.input_field :email_address, label: false %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

This shows the error message properly (e.g. "is invalid"), but if I click off the input and then back on again, it adds another message (e.g. it would say "is invalid is invalid"). For example, two sequential invalid entries and then a blank entry would give:

[image: errors are not removed]

Is there any way to have simple_form remove the existing error message before adding a new one?

Comment: Any reason why you're using `f.input_field` instead of `f.input`?

Comment: @depa yes, f.input wraps it in a div, which causes it to not display inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I solved this using some ghetto js, but would still like to know if the functionality I mentioned above is built in.  The divs are still there, they're just hidden instead of all showing together.  Would be great to have them actually removed by the form validation...

```
$('input.email-address-input').on 'keyup', () ->
    $(this).parent('form').siblings('.help-inline').hide()
```